# PHP IBaseQuery not updating immediately?

Tags: php, firebird

I connect the normal way:

```
$dbh = ibase_connect($host, $username, $password) OR die("could not connect");
```

Then I run a query:

```
ibase_query($dbh, 'ALTER TABLE USERS ADD OLDUSERPASS VARCHAR(32) COLLATE NONE') or die(ibase_errmsg());
```

Directly after this I run:

```
ibase_query($dbh, 'UPDATE USERS SET OLDUSERPASS = USERPASS') or die(ibase_errmsg());
```

It complains:

```
Column unknown OLDUSERPASS At line 1
```

But when I look in the DB, the column has been created. So, for some reason that split second after run ALTER, the query is not actually committed to the server.

Any ideas why?

Comment: In the `ALTER TABLE` you alter table `USERS` but in the `UPDATE` you use table `WWW_USERS` - is that just a typo here in SO or in your real code too?

Comment: Typo. Sorry... will fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try
`ibase_commit($dbh`) after alter statement

Answer (score 2):

In Firebird, DDL is under transaction control and you are not allowed to use newly created objects (tables, columns, etc) within the same transaction. So you will first need to commit before executing a query that uses that object.